# How to call factory girl with the same model name but belongs to different rails 3.2.12 engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot, factory

There is misc_definition model in both projectx and customerx rails 3.2.12 engine. Projectx and customerx are needed in the same rails app. Now there is a problem about how to call the factory girl with the same model name but belongs to different rails engines:

The factory girl definitions for misc_definition in customerx is:

```
factory :misc_definition, :class => 'Customerx::MiscDefinition' do
...
```

The file name is `customerx_misc_definitions.rb`

The factory girl definition for misc_definition in projectx is:

```
factory :misc_definition, :class => 'Projectx::MiscDefinition' do
...
```

The file name is `projectx_misc_definitions.rb`

Here is how the factory girl (for misc_definition in customerx) in rspec is called:

```
cate = FactoryGirl.create(:misc_definition, :for_which => 'customer_status', :name => 'order category')
```

The rspec error is:

```
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl/decorator.rb:10:in `method_missing': Factory already registered: misc_definiti
on (FactoryGirl::DuplicateDefinitionError)
```

How to call factory girl of the same model name but belong to different rails engine?

Comment: Are you manually loading your engine's factories in your main app? I have an app w/several engines, and the engine factories are not available by default.

Comment: Probably not the answer you want, but it may be easiest to ensure the factories don't share names.

Comment: Factory for engine has to be copied over manually. The factory was automatically created the rails g model command and the name was given.